# Powershell hashtable not accessible outside a foreach

Tags: powershell

I have function with a foreach inside a foreach. My hashtable set inside the foreach is not accessible outside and I don't understand why.

The scope of sampletab is in "Script"

```
    function Generate(){
        $script:sampletab=@{}
        $y=0
        $samples = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT * FROM ..."

        foreach ($row in $samples) 
        {
            $paramID = $row["xxx"]
            $query = "SELECT * FROM ... ${paramID};"
            $parameters = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query               
            foreach ($row in $parameters)
            {   
                $name = "coucou"
                $name = $row["name"]
                $sampletab[$y] = @{
                    $name = $row["value"]
                }           
            }               
            $y++    
            break
        }
    }
    Generate
    echo $sampletab[0].Keys  # gives me only 1 key, should be 20 keys
```

Comment: Which `foreach`? You have two, and both use `$row` as the iteration variable, I doubt this is really your intention?

Comment: $samples and $parameters are results of  an  Invoke-Sqlcmd

Comment: Don't overwrite your samples and row variables.

Comment: Can you provide [mcve]?

Comment: yes sure, I modified it

Comment: Why do you expect 20 keys? Here `$sampletab[$y] = @{ $name = $row["value"] }` you assign `$sampletab[$y]` hash table with only one key. Plain assignment replace previous value, but not combine with it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found it. It's missing the "+="

```
        $name = $row["name"]
        $sampletab[$y] += @{
            $name = $row["value"]
        }
```

thank you !